# Alamofire Time Out Not Working

Tags: swift2, alamofire

i am using Alamofire in swift 2.0 to perform post requests. everything is working fine but now i have to set a time out interval on the request here is what i have done :

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300;
            let Manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)


            Manager.request(.POST, URL, parameters:param as? [String : AnyObject])......
```

now the response.result.isSuccess  is always false no matter how many seconds i put (1 to 1000). why is that? and note that the call is not waiting for 1000 seconds and then getting this response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone having problem this worked for me.

set a global variable

```
    var alamofireManager : Alamofire.Manager?
```

then

```
 let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 1 // seconds for testing

            self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)

             self.alamofireManager!.request(.POST, URL, parameters: param as? [String : AnyObject],  headers: headers)
.responseString
                { response in

                    print ("the response: \(response.description)") //will return a timeout error
```